# ActionScript 3.0 The Definition Of Base Class GameFrameWork Was Not Found

Tags: actionscript-3

```
package com.efg.games.stubgame {
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.text.TextFormatAlign; 
import flash.geom.Point;
import com.efg.framework.FrameWorkStates;
import com.efg.framework.GameFrameWork; 
import com.efg.framework.BasicScreen;
import com.efg.framework.ScoreBoard;
import com.efg.framework.SideBySideScoreElement;

public class Main extends GameFrameWork{
```

(Note: This is just one section of the code).

The Error is stated in the title.

The route to GameFrameWork.as is classes/com/efg/framework/GameFrameWork.as

the route is

```
Source
    classes
        com
            efg
                framework
                    GameFrameWork.as
    projects
        stubgame
            flashIDE
                stubGame.fla
                stubGame.as
                com
                    efg
                        games
                            stubgame
                                Main.as
                                StubGame.as
```

Comment: Are you certain the the `classes` folder is one of the project's source paths?

Comment: should classes be under projects folder?

Comment: It should either be in the same directory as your FLA, or added manually via `File -> ActionScript Settings`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `../../../../../../../classes/` to your "Source Path" panel.

[image: Source Path]

Comment: I did that but forgot to add /classes/ at the end

Answer (score 0):

One option is to simply merge the com folder from classes into the com folder from flashIDE.  If you divided them out like that though, you may not want to do this.

I'm not sure which IDE you're using, but in the project's properties, the IDE should have a place for you to add folders to the "build path".  If you add classes's com folder to the build path, it should look in there as well for class definitions and such.